# How to get a correct return code of Config Server Firewall (csf) after adding to deny list?

Tags: linux, bash, return

If an IP is not in the deny list, then to deny an IP in CSF, I use the following command:

```
csf -d 192.144.22.22 > /dev/null
RETVAL=$?
echo $RETVAL
# Output: 0
```

If the IP (192.144.22.22) is already in the deny list, then using the same above code will still return 0.

I need different return code from CSF based on this 2 conditions when using `csf -d $IP_ADDRESS`. How do you handle this return code programmatically ?

---

Another way I can think of is using grep, but I don't like this method because the success string is badly written:

For example if csf detected already in deny list, I got the following message:

```
deny failed: 192.144.22.22 is in already in the deny file /etc/csf/csf.deny 1 times
```

If not in the deny list (success), then I got the following:

```
Adding 192.144.22.22 to csf.deny and iptables DROP...
csf: IPSET adding [192.144.22.22] to set [chain_DENY]
```

But the success text is badly written. No keyword "success" here that I can use with grep. I can also use this and it works

```
test=$(csf -d 104.244.42.3 | grep 'deny failed')
 if [ -z "$test" ]; then # If result test is empty , not 'deny failed'
     echo "Success"
 else
     echo "Failed"
 fi
```

but, this doesn't mean it's always success because some other failed strings (without the string 'deny failed') might appear which is not always success.

Is there another way (without using grep) to achieve this?

Comment: If the address is already in the address list, do you not get a return code of 1. If so, cannot you just use the return code in your condition?

Comment: That's the problem. it doesn't return code 1 if it's already in address list instead i got 0 for both conditions. The problem with using grep is that, it's just an assumption of a string 'deny failed'. What if csf has another error like file access error which does not contain 'deny failed' ? Then it's not good to use grep. The code is just an example, I can write a return 0 or return 1 but the return code is just an assumption from the string ( 'deny failed' )

Comment: Can you not parse the file /etc/csf/csf.deny directly for the ip address to be added?

Comment: Yeah. Don't write directly to the file. Check to see if the ip address is in the file first and then use the csf command to add it if necessary.

Comment: @RamanSailopal A good idea and I think it is possible to manually write it in /etc/csf/csf.deny and do checking. I have other scripts that use csf and do blocking automatically, so the file keep changing by itself (and im afraid it's going to be a problem), that's why i feel like using csf command is safer because it has more error checking. I will try to do this manually. You just gave me an idea

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RamanSailopal for giving an idea. Instead of using csf to check error message, we can manually check the IP address whether it is exist or not in /etc/csf/csf.deny:

If it exists, then we don't do anything, else we use csf to block the IP. By using this method I can do more manual checking. Example of the solution:

```
   check_ip=$(grep -F "${ip_address} " "/etc/csf/csf.deny")
   if [ -z "$check_ip" ]; then
            echo "Blocking $ip_address in CSF ... "
            csf -d $ip_address
            csf -ra > /dev/null # in-case
   else
            echo "IP is already in the blocked list"
            exit 1      
   fi
```